# What is a manifest.json file, and where can I find it on my machine?

Tags: google-chrome

I assume that it is for chrome.  I have read that I can set the permissions in that file to avoid XSS errors while developing.

Comment: Every chrome extensions require manifest.json file, that **describes the app**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many json files for your chrome experience from Native chrome json files to json files for chrome extensions. Most of them can be found at

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\
```

Most manifest.json files are found for extensions in

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions
```

Answer (score 9):

In linux mine are located in .config directory:

```
./.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/bjnkloegafmkhgpjglcbldhaokjpandj/1.0.0.0_0/manifest.json
./.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/gbammbheopgpmaagmckhpjbfgdfkpadb/1.9.1.8_0/manifest.json
./.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/aknpkdffaafgjchaibgeefbgmgeghloj/1.1.2.1_0/_locales/ar/messages.json
./.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/aknpkdffaafgjchaibgeefbgmgeghloj/1.1.2.1_0/_locales/zh-TW/messages.json
./.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/aknpkdffaafgjchaibgeefbgmgeghloj/1.1.2.1_0/_locales/es-419/messages.json
./.config/transmission/settings.json
./.config/transmission/stats.json
```

Answer (score 7):

For the mac it's located here:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions
```

For further reading: [Where does Chrome store userscripts.user.js files on a mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176596/where-does-chrome-store-userscripts-user-js-files-on-a-mac)