# Where does Chrome store userscripts.user.js files on a mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, userscripts, root

i want to know where chrome stores the userscripts that are installed.

i couldn't find any answer elsewhere.

i'm on a mac.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Finding the extension ID

If you have many user scripts, we'll need to find the extension ID of your user script for the next step. Go to chrome://extensions/ in your address bar, or navigate to the wrench icon, then Tools -> Extensions.

Under each extension, you'll see an entry like `ID: inoibihbncpenbmllpjoonoaadechdng`. This is the extension ID. Find your script, and observe the ID.

These user scripts are usually stored in:

`~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions`

If this path makes sense, you can skip the next section. Otherwise, follow along below for more detailed instructions.

### Finding your Extensions folder

Go to your user folder. You can do this by opening Finder, and going to Go -> Home. Then we want to navigate to Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/

If you're not using multiple Chrome profiles, at this point you should be able to just go to Default/Extensions/

### Extension layout

Each extension will be in a folder, named after their extension ID. Inside this, we'll have a version number, then any metadata files. In the latest version of Chrome, userscripts will have at minimum a `script.js` file and `manifest.json`. You're looking for `script.js`, which contains the actual Javascript.

Comment: open it up and take a peek :) it's a description/metadata file