# Escaped Script tag inside a Select box option (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an HTML page which contains a dropdownlist .

```
<html>
    <body>
        <select>
            <option >1</option>
            <option >2</option>
            <option >3</option>
            <option >&lt;script&gt;alert('XSS')&lt;/script&gt;</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

**In Chrome the select box won't open.**

When I open it in FireFox, the dropdownlist opens, but in Chrome it does not.
Fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/nghiadthp/3mpmkfr8/

Comment: your mean is `alert('XSS')`?

Comment: Make a demo on JSFiddle, CodePen or similar

Comment: @Alex : yes , i mean that !!

Comment: @Nuno Arruda : this is jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/nghiadthp/3mpmkfr8/      you should try it in 2 browser chrome and firefox to see difference.
Thank you

Comment: Runs fine on my side on both browsers. It's just a simple select list... What's exactly the issue you're having? Post a screenshot

Comment: @NunoArruda : did you try to click on dropdownlist ? when i run in Chrome , i click on dropdownlist , then it doesn't show option. But in firefox  , it can show option .
Thank NunoArruda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome has a feature that can be turned off by setting this flag in your Chrome (icon) > Properties Target path:

```
...ome.exe" --disable-web-security
```

**Despite that**, what you're trying will *suffer* from this goods:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

> CSP Level 2 offers backward compatibility for inline scripts by allowing you to whitelist specific inline scripts using either a cryptographic nonce (number used once) or a hash

So you might want probably to create a .json [manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862215/what-is-a-manifest-json-file-and-where-can-i-find-it-on-my-machine) with `"unsafe-inline"` property that has that exact (unescaped) `script` converted in SHA256

```
<script>alert('XSS')</script> // >> convert it to SHA256
```

> Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'sha256-sha256-41f152968d8d75de3055b59b194f3a5a993b65b06c1586d7dda9d73be115271d'

---

or using a `nonce` property:

```
&lt;script nonce=a3afdc68d2731d5187f58e833610c951&gt;alert('XSS')&lt;/script&gt;
```

must match your manifest's script-src:

> Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'nonce-a3afdc68d2731d5187f58e833610c951'

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest
https://w3c.github.io/webappsec/specs/content-security-policy/
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/

So Chrome will not allow you to perform as you might expect with **inline `script`s**
(test using `&lt;span&gt;` and it'll work!)
without *you* knowing exactly the madness you're doing.
BTW, no element is allowed into `option` tag, escaped or not, so Chrome is really smart about it. Specially regarding XSS prevention.